# Terminated when debugging with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to create a google map in android using instructions as per Google Map Android API2 tutorial. All steps are completed and uploading app to device has been successfully done. Unfortunately it stops before the map is shown on device with the following error log.

```
{
DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2205    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2255 
        ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 146    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1240  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5171    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 797  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 564 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any LogCat output? Try running in on an emulator or eclipse before deploying to a device.

Comment: hai csmckelvey. It is working now. The main cause is i replace both the word of API_KEY in { <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/> } instead of just replacing on android:value...